# Complex CSS selectors for integration testing using webdriverjs

Tags: javascript, css, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to write some integration tests using the following tech-stack: Selenium(JavaScript bindings), WebdriverJS, Mocha & Chai.

I am essentially trying to follow [this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/headless-functional-testing-with-selenium-and-phantomjs/), which for some reason suggested using `WebdriverJS` as opposed to the "official" SeleniumJS bindings.

I want to set up a simple script to navigate to our homepage, and click on the link that leads to the `About` page. The HTML is as follows:

```
<ul id="nav">
    ...
    <li>
       <a href="/about/">
           <span>About</span>
       </a>
    </li>
    ...
</ul>
```

Now, I wrote this code to click on this link:

```
client
  .url(my_url)
  .getTitle (err, title) ->
    expect(err).to.be.null
  .click 'a[href*="about"]', (err) ->
    expect(err).to.be.null
```

Unfortunately, the last line always throws an error. I realize I am using nested CSS selectors, which may be tough to parse. But, when I try to access this element using `jQuery` from the browser, I do get the object with the exact same line.

Any ideas as to what the problem may be in this case?

**Note** (personal): The documentation of `WebdriverJS` is extremely poor, and the `.click()` function essentially has only two lines of explanation.

Comment: I would say that JavaScript and Webdriver is one of the less popular combinations. Python seems to be used a lot more so I would see no reason why your tests shouldn't be written in Python

Comment: Well what error? Even if it doesn't throw an error, you appear to be using jQuery-style "extended" CSS selectors. I say this because `has` and `contains` are not part of the CSS standard and commonly used in jQuery (from Sizzle). I would suggest you **do not use them**.

Comment: I agree with Arran and Robbie.  Use standard Python to write your selectors, not Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: The "What technology to use" part of the question is out of scope for stackoverflow. I've deleted them so that the question doesn't need to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Webdriverjs supports selecting an element with xpath, you could use that. My initial impression is it's harder than to work with jquery-style selector, but eventually it turns out not so shabby.

For your selector above, one could rewrite that in xpath as below:

```
//a/span[text()="About"]
```

Be warned that the selector above is actually selecting the `span` inside the link as opposed to selecting the link which contains this span. I'm not too sure how to select the link itself like in your case, but I think xpath also supports something like that. For your test, the above selector still may work...